# how to convert an existing sqlite3 rails project to postgresql rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner in rails development. till now I was creating small modules using, sqlite3 now I want to convert it to PostgreSQL please help me with step by step procedure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to install postgres in your OS.
Then replace gem 'sqlite3' to gem 'pg' in Gem file.
Then bundle install command need to run.

Or you can directly create a project through rails new my_app_name --database=postgresql command